# meteor: how to filter local collection by date

Tags: date, meteor, find

I have a subscribed collection `entries` which consists of entries with a type attribute (e.g. "post" or "article") and two dates for availability (`available_from` and `available_to`). These entries are uploaded into the database via a RESTful API and the values for `available_from` and `available_to` are stored as `ISODates` in the form

`"available_to" : ISODate("2017-06-01T00:00:00Z")`

The problem is that once I try to do a search (values are fetched from a form and a search hash is created in the following manner) it comes up empty:

```
"click #search-trigger": ->
  $entry_type = $('#fullsearch-entry-type').val()
  $from = Date.create(moment($('#fullsearch-from').val(), "DD.MM.YYYY").format())
  $to = Date.create(moment($('#fullsearch-to').val(), "DD.MM.YYYY").format())

  searchHash =
    available_from:
      $gte: $from
    available_to:
      $lte: $to
    entry_type: $entry_type

  console.log searchHash
  console.log typeof $from
  console.log typeof $to

  console.log Entry.find(searchHash).fetch()
```

The dates are converted to the correct date object (since the value in the input field is in the form of DD.MM.YYYY and would otherwise be just a string if I'm assuming correctly) with SugarJS.

I tried different variants of rewriting the date values, left out one of the two dates or to leave out my search hash and enter the query options by hand into the `find()` query but to no avail. I hope someone can point me in the right direction because I'm already pulling my hair out over this :)

Comment: Are you sure the variable $from and $to are in the ISODate format? Otherwhis this might be the problem. You can also try to conver the ISODate format to the Date type. because $from is from thaat type

Comment: I also tried to build the query like so:

`Entry.find({entry_type: "entry", available_from: { $gte: { $date: $from }}})` just to make sure but still no luck. But I suspect you're right, maybe my date values aren't ISODate - how can I convert them (since I supposed SugarJS does this when using `Date.create()`) to ISODate (or convert my collection's dates to another type)?

Comment: Can you really pass a moment to sugarjs? Seems like a rather error-prone way to parse a date, maybe you should be using either sugar or moment, but both together seems strange to me. I would go back to plain javascript for the dates bit so you know what's going on. Did you log the dates to be sure you're getting back exactly what you expected from sugar? Try some ordinary javascript: var myDateParser = function(stringWithDots){
    var splitted = stringWithDots.split('.');

    var newDateString = splitted[2] + '-' + splitted[1] + '-' + splitted[0];
    return new Date(newDateString);

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mwarren stated, the problem was Sugar + moment - once I went a few steps back and stuck to plain JS date, my problems went away.